# Crunchbang/Debian apt-preferences

Tags: debian, apt, crunchbang

So I did manage to set up apt-preferences but I'm not sure if I did it correctly.
So basically what I want is, if I have the need I want to install packages from
TESTING, UNSTABLE and DEB-MULTIMEDIA and that (ONLY) these Packages also get updates from the specific Repo. But as a "base" I want to have the STABLE-Version. Would be nice if somebody could check if I set this up correctly, because I'm not quite sure how the Pin-Priority works...

so this i my sources.list

```
## CRUNCHBANG
## Compatible with Debian Wheezy, but use at your own risk.
deb http://packages.crunchbang.org/waldorf waldorf main
#deb-src http://packages.crunchbang.org/waldorf waldorf main

## DEBIAN-STABLE
deb http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main contrib non-free

## DEBIAN-BACKPORTS
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main contrib non-free

## DEBIAN-TESTING
deb http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free

## DEBIAN-UNSTABLE
deb http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free

## DEBIAN MULTIMEDIA
#deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy main non-free

## DEBIAN SECURITY
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

and my apt/preferences

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=waldorf
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 800

Package: *
Pin: release a=wheezy-backports
Pin-Priority: 650

Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 400

Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 90

Package: *
Pin: origin *.deb-multimedia.org
Pin-Priority: 10
```

Comment: You're mixing Debian repos with another distribution? Is that Ok? Note that at least wheezy-backports already sets a priority server-side, which is what you usually want, so you don't need to set your own. From my machine it looks like 100. I think you want testing preferences under 100 too. Read `man apt_preferences` if you haven't already.

Comment: The Crunchbang-Repo was there after the installation, I´m not quite sure if I can remove it safely, because I´m using crunchbang...and yes I read the man-page and lots of other documentation on the web, but I´m not 100% sure if I got it right...

Comment: Just curious what the advantage is of running Crunchbang vs Debian directly.

Comment: I think they have some updated/fixed packages in there, http://packages.crunchbang.org/waldorf/pool/main/